# Scrapy xml extractor doesn't get full table

Tags: xml, shell, scrapy, extract

So I am attempting to get a bunch of data from a table at:
https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/WEB.AX/history?period1=1427720400&period2=1499436000&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d 
using scrapy shell.

The xml extractor code I'm using is just

```
response.xpath(".//tr//text()").extract()
```

This gets me some of the data, but when I go into the developer console it says 'not all nodes are displayed' and so I can't get all the data. Was just wondering what I need to do in order to get all the data.

Thanks.

Comment: The site uses javascript to load results in chunks as you scroll, and Scrapy doesn't run Javascript without an additional component like [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash).  Have you tried the [yahoo-finance](https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance) package to access this data through API?

Comment: @jschnurr no I have never heard of that. It looks very useful. Thank you very much!